# Let A be a commutative ring. Let $I \subsetneq A$. Show that there exists a maximal ideal $m \subseteq A$ such that $I \subseteq m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have this exercise, but I feel like something is wrong. As far as I know, if $m$ is a maximal ideal, then $m \subsetneq A$. But with this hypothesis, I think to take $I = \lbrace 1_A \rbrace$, so the only ideal that contains $I$ is $A$, so $I$ is not maximal.

EDIT:

I wrote something wrong. I didn't meant that I was the ideal, but that if $m$ is an ideal such that $I \subseteq m$, then $m = A$, so m is not maximal

Comment: Do you know Zorn's lemma? You need to assume that the ideal is **proper** and the the commutative ring contains unity, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Perhaps in the question it is meant that $I$ is an ideal in $A$. So the question reads: every proper ideal is contained in some maximal ideal.

Comment: See https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54308edae4b02ca7f4976556/t/5532ec53e4b07041cd90ec2b/1429400659002/Maximal+Ideal+Proof.pdf

Comment: @Ravi: I thought to find a proper ideal, but if $m$ is an ideal that contains the unity, then $m=A$ I think. I remember now they told be that a ring might not contain the unity, but we are considering rings that do.

Comment: @Adayah: I think what you said might be it. I'll give it a thought considering that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $I=\{1\}$ is usually not an ideal, unless $1$ is the only element of $A$. That is because the ideal axioms require that for any $a$, if $1\in I$, we also have $a=a\cdot 1\in I$. Hence, $A\subseteq I$ and consequently, $A=I$. So this is not a contradiction because only *proper* ideals are contained in a maximal one.

Comment: Thanks. I've realized from this that I said something wrong. What I meant is not that I is the ideal, but that if $I \subseteq m$, and m is an ideal, then $m = A$, so m is not maximal

Comment: Dear @DaniSeidler, that is completely true. And indeed, the statement from the title of your question is only true if $I$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal $(1)$ generates the whole ring, so we usually do not consider it an ideal. A different approach is via Zorn's lemma. If you take the collection of ideals that contain $I$, and any chain in it, we just have to show that the chain has an upper bound (as in an ideal that contains $I$.)

This amounts to checking that

$$M:=\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} I_i$$
is a proper ideal since it clearly contains $I$. It is proper since $1 \notin I_i$ for any $i \in \mathcal{I}$.

To see that it is an ideal ,note that it is closed under multiplication by any $r \in A$, since for any $a\in M$, we have that $a \in I_i$ for some $i$, so $ra \in I_i$. This method also shows the existence of additive inverses by taking $r=-1$.

Closure under addition is the part that uses the ordering. WLOG, suppose that $I_i \subset I_j$. Then $i+j \subset I_j$, since $i,j \in I_j$.

Hence, $M$ is an ideal that bounds the chain, so Zorn's lemma applies.